# Symfony 2 keep _target_path even on wrong password

Tags: security, symfony

When authenticating using Symfony 2.10, if I post a request to login check as configured in sercurity.yml:

```
form_login:
    login_path: /account/login
    check_path: /account/login_check
```

The _target_path is correctly set on the form.

But if the user now types in the wrong password, the _target_path is lost and when the user now types in the right password, it will get redirected to the default place, in my case the front page.

I would like the security handler to keep the _target_path all the way, even if the user types  the wrong password.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I find only one way: create new failure_handler for form_login

Add in your security.yml:

```
form_login
    failure_handler: some_failure_handler_id
```

In that service:

```
public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    ...

    $target_path = $request->request->get('_target_path');
    if ($target_path) {
        $request->getSession()->set('_security.login.target_path', $target_path);
    }

    ...
}
```

In SecurityController:

```
if ($back_url = $session->get('_security.login.target_path')) {
    $session->remove('_security.login.target_path');
}
```

And set target_path again in form:

```
{% if back_url %}                               
    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ back_url }}" />
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Old post but really helpfull :P

Comment: I have opened the issue, maybe someone will implement this or something else natively :) https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21628

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `use_referer` to `true` [[see reference](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/security.html)]:

```
form_login:
    ...
    use_referer: true
```

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that your `_target_path` will not be erased - you can set it in your twig template as current uri:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ app.request.uri }}" name="_target_path" />
```

Comment: that would redirect to login form, not referer.